# TYPO3 is it possible to skip 9.5 update

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-10.x

I'm currently preparing to update my TYPO3 8.7 site to a 10.0, this update is set for April since that's when the LTS release will be. However, I was wondering if it's best practice to update to 9.5 first or to skip said version and go straight to 10.0.

Of course, backups will be made before doing any of this work and my server can handle the 10.0 version since we have an empty one running at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade to 9.5 first to execute all the core & extension updaters (database)
[see documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/9.5/en-us/Upgrade/UpgradeToV9.html)

In my experience, you can just do the extension updaters and then go to the next version but you will have to fix your site extension in version 10. See the [changelog](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/) for all breaking changes

Comment: Alright, seems like 9.5 is a required upgrade to get to 10.0 judging by the links you just send